# Joomla component SEF url router

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-sef-urls

I am trying to generate SEF urls for joomla component.
I want generate and parse the given url into SEF URL. Please suggest or help me out.

Original URLs:

for item and brand
1. mysite.com/store-locator/storelocatoritem/storelocatoritem?cid[0]=6529-a-lange-sohne&bid[0]=132

for city
2. mystore.com/store-locator/storelocator?city_id[0]=abu-dhabi

for brand and city
3. mysite.com/store-locator/storelocator?bid[0]=74&city_id[0]=abu-dhabi

for item,brand and city
4. mysite.com/store-locator/storelocatoritem/storelocatoritem?cid[0]=6901-breguet&bid[0]=74&citid[0]=abu-dhabi

I want to generate SEF urls and want to parse them.

Kindly help me out in doing this.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have tried anything yet so I would suggest you start here - http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Comment: Thanks for reply and suggestion Brent. I have successfully buildRoute. I am stuck on parsRoute phase.
mystore.com/store-locator/storelocator/abu-dhabi

Now I need to get "abu-dhabi" in parsRoute. How can I get it or any other query-string parameter ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at "A More Advanced Example" on the documentation? Are you adding the city_id in BuildRoute?